# Added Div not working click function

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my scenario , i have to use class to add div , this may easily solve with onClick function, but i require this to complete my task, 
.click(function() is not working on new element , javascript /jquery may store element onload or what???

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/q061gno2/1/)

```
<div class="add">
  <div class="anyRow">Hello<hr/></div>
</div>



$('.anyRow').click(function(){
$('.add').append('<div class="anyRow">Hello</hr></div>')
});
```

Comment: delegate click event: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/  http://jsfiddle.net/q061gno2/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `on()` method as the deprecated `live()` one, to delegate click for future new elements.

```
$(document).on("click", ".anyRow", function() {
  $('.add').append('<div class="anyRow">Hello</hr></div>');
});
```

Comment: OP jsFiddle is including jQuery 1.6.4, you should use `delegate()` (not sure about OP real case use)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using in real case (as in posted jsFiddle) jQuery v1.6.4, you should use `.delegate()` method:

```
$('.add').delegate('.anyRow', 'click', function () {
    $('.add').append('<div class="anyRow">Hello</hr></div>')
});
```

### -DEMO-

http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 1):

For older jquery versions you can use `live` function if html is changed dynamically (I saw you using an older jquery version in the fiddle)

```
$('.add').live( 'click', function () {
    $('.add').append('<div class="anyRow">Hello</hr></div>')
});
```

Comment: live is depreciated function ..Thank You

Comment: `delegate()` should be used, not `live()`  `Since the .live() method handles events once they have propagated to the top of the document, it is not possible to stop propagation of live events. Similarly, events handled by .delegate() will propagate to the elements to which they are delegated; event handlers bound on any elements below it in the DOM tree will already have been executed by the time the delegated event handler is called. These handlers, therefore, may prevent the delegated handler from triggering by calling event.stopPropagation() or returning false.`

Answer (score 0):

The method bellow applies event handlers to elements even before they exist

```
$("#parent-element").on("click", "#new-element", function() {
    // your code
});
```